# Pygame fallback font

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

Is there a way in Pygame to set a font and make it so, if the character I'm trying to display is not available in this font, then it tries to take it from another font?

**Example:**

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

s = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 500))
s.fill((255, 255, 255))

s.blit(
    pygame.font.SysFont('FreeMono', 25, True, False).render(
        '(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ Hmm… ಠ_ಠ', True, (0,0,0)
    ),
    (0, 200)
)

pygame.display.flip()
```

The above code displays almost all characters except 4 of them (`）`, `︵` and the 2 `ಠ`).

**Police used:** http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/freefont/

Researches on the net yielded nothing about the issue.

I'm using Python 3, if it matters.

**BONUS:** I don't think it fits SO but alternatively, if someone knows a good free pan-font containing ton of characters in it, I take it.

Comment: Fixedsys Excelsior is a great font, albiet very "digital looking". It might not be appropriate for your style, but I can confirm it has a wealth of Unicode characters. I suppose you could always open up the font you're using and just add those characters, licenses allowing.

Answer (score 0):

You could give google fonts a try. Or searching for .ttf fonts online

Here are some google fonts i found that support the characters you are trying to display.

- Noto Sans Japanese
- Noto Sans Korean
- Noto Sans Traditional Chinese
- Klee One
- Rampart One
- Kiwi Maru

litte note,

- Use pygame.font.Font() if you gonna use .ttf